# Problems loading 5M instances with Weka API

Tags: java, eclipse, api, heap-memory, weka

I have a database with more or less 5 million rows. I want to load them as instances from a Java program in eclipse using the Weka api, in order to apply data mining techniques. However, I get a heap overflow if I try loading more than 2.5 millions,  even if I have increased the heap memory for Eclipse in run configurations with -Xmx2048M. my computer has 4GB of RAM, and gets stuck if I use more memory. Anyway, loading 2.5 millions takes too much time.

I am thinking to load them in fractions, but I do not think it is the best idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Weka API, but if you need load huge of data from relation database to memory best way do it use [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29). If you use JDBC you should use [Scrollable Reslut Set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28612).

Comment: I have been looking around options to implement Cursor and Scrollable Result Set. I am going to try with Scrollable Result Set, as I am using a JDBC. Anyway, it makes getting the instances tougher. I will have to get the rows one by one and transform them to instances on the fly.

Comment: Ok. I have implemented a Scrollable Result set and it ables to do the query to the database. But as I need to transform each of the row in a Weka instance, I get the OutOfMemoryError before transforming the whole result set. Knowing this, it seems that we will have to change the design of our data mining program i order to do smaller queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing :
    Go to program files '\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6' and then RunWeka.ini. Open it in notepad and change the line        in the middle of the file ***'maxheap = 512m'*** to ***'maxheap = 2000m'***.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I do not find that file anywhere. Although, I do not think the problem can be fixed giving more memory, because like I said I give to the execution all the memory I can using the arguments and still get the overflow.